# Best way to create a shared data source with Report Builder

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I am using report builder 3.0 (very similar to SQL server reporting services) to create reports for users on an application using SQL server 2012 database.

To set the scene, we have a database with over 1200 tables.  We actually only need about 100 of these for reporting purposes.  But it is very common that we need to combine fields from multiple tables together to get a common resource of data that my colleagues and I need for our reports.

Eg if I want a view of a customer, I would want to bring in information about the customer from the customer_table, information about his phone details from the Phone table, information about his account(s) from the accounts table and so on. Then I might need another view of the accounts - account type, various balance amounts, opening date, status etc.

What I would love to do is create a "customer view" where we combine all these fields into a single combined virtual table.  Then we have an "Accounts view".  It would be easier to use, easier to manage etc.  Then we use this for all our reports going forwards.  And when we need to, we can combine the customer and accounts view to use on a report plus actual tables into one combo-dataset to use on a report.

I am unsure about the right way to do this.

I see I can create a data source.  This doesn't seem right as this appears to be what one might do if working off 2 or more databases.  We are using just 1 database.

Then there are report models.  It seems these are being deprecated and phased out so this doesn't seem a good option.

Finally I see we can create shared datasets.  However, this option (as far as I can tell) won't allow me to combine this with another dataset.  So using the example above, I won't be able to combine the customer view and the account view with this approach to use for a report to display details about the customer and his/her accounts.

Would appreciate guidance on the best way to achieve what I am trying to do...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can only speak from personal experience, but using the the data source approach has been good for our purposes.  We have a single database with 50+ tables in it. This is linked to as a shared data source in the project so is available to all 50+ reports.

We then use Stored Procedures to make the information in the databases available to the reports, each report has it's own Stored Procedure that joins as many tables as required to provide the data for the report.  The advantage of using Stored Procedures also allows you to only return rows you are interested in, rather than entire tables.

I'm not certain if this is the kind of answer that you were after, but describes how we solve a similar (smaller) issue.